# Transfer pictures via adb, while preserving the ability to pick a better shot later

Tags: photos, google-pixel-6

When I view a picture on my Pixel6, the phone suggests a "*Top Shot*" and lets me "*pick a better shot*".

I would like to transfer my pictures to a hard drive using `adb`, while retaining that ability.
I don't use Google Photos. Phone not rooted.

Is that possible?
If needed I can modify any Camera app's setting, or pre-process the pictures before using `adb` using any app, or post-process them afterwards using any software.

[image]

Comment: The source of a "Top Shot" is according to Google's documentation a "motion picture" (effectively a video not a picture). https://support.google.com/googlecamera/answer/9937175

Comment: @Robert: Interesting! Would you know whether the video gets transferred by adb? I only see JPGs on the destination hard drive.

Comment: Sorry I don't know where and in which format the Camera app saves the data use to provide the Top Shot picker.